# OrientDB - key-value store in C#

Tags: c#, orientdb

I need to use OrientDB to create key-value store and perform some basic operations such as add, remove, modify or print some data. Problem is I really don't understand how am I supposed to do that since there is no API or DataType dedicated to k-v stores. From what I undestood from documentation, Im supposed to create my own classes that will act as buckets but I don't know if that is correct or how that class has to look like.

Answer (score 0):

The class in Orientdb is like a "model" for your key-value store( or like a table in sql).

For example:
If you want to store books, you should create a Book class in OrientDb with properties: title, author, ect. These properties will be keys in your key-value store.

```
CREATE CLASS Book

CREATE PROPERTY Book.title STRING

CREATE PROPERTY Book.author STRING

INSERT INTO Book SET title = 'Harry Potter and the cursed child', author = 'J. K. Rowling'
```